# Jquery Hash Navigation

Tags: jquery, hash

I have a simple javascript function to get hash variables:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
        nav_anchor()
    });
    function nav_anchor() {
        var aurl = location.hash;
        aurl = aurl.split('#');
        if (aurl[1]) { alert(aurl[1]); }
        else { alert("Empty");  }
    }
});
```

```html
<a href="#a=1&aa=10">11111111111</a>
<a href="#b=1&bb=10">22222222222222</a>
<a href="#c=1&cc=10">333333333</a>
```

But if I click in the link I receive the previous var.

Example:

If my first Click is `11111` I receive message `Empty` and if my second click is `222222` I receive `a=1&aa=10`

Comment: It seems the location.hash is applied after you call your `nav_anchor()`.

Answer (score 5):

http://jsbin.com/uxitoy/2/edit

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
        nav_anchor(this);
    });
    function nav_anchor(o) {
        var aurl = o.hash;
        aurl = aurl.split('#');
        if (aurl[1].length>0) { alert(aurl[1]); }
        else { alert("Empty");  }
    }
});
```

Comment: It seems like nav_anchor function may be defined anywhere. It is not necessary to keep it inside $.ready call.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the click event is fired *before* the hash fragment is appended to the URL. Instead of getting the hash from the URL, get it from the link:

```
$("a").click(function(){
    nav_anchor(this)
});

function nav_anchor(el) {
    var aurl = el.href;
    aurl = aurl.split('#');
    if (aurl[1]) { alert(aurl[1]); }
    else { alert("Empty");  }
}
```

If you want to get the variables on page load, then you would need to read it from the URL using `location.hash`.

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uxswK/1)

Comment: no need to send $(this)..this is enough. leave it dom element.